# Show that any relation R on any set A is symmetric if and only if $R = R^{-1}$

Tags: functions, relations

For phone users,

Prove that any relation $R$ on any set $A$ is symmetric if and only if $R = R^{-1}$.

In fact, it is, but how?

Comment: Just use the definitions of symmetric and $\cdot^{-1}$ for relations

Comment: For phone users?? What do you mean?

Comment: @ajotatxe LaTex is not working on Stack Exchange Topic in the smartphone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for a way to write out a formal proof of this rather self-evident result.

First suppose that  $R=R^{-1}$. Then

$(a,b)\in R \implies (b,a)\in R^{-1}\implies (b,a)\in R$. Therefore $R$ is symmetric.

Next suppose that $R$ is symmetric. Then we have both:

$(a,b)\in R \implies (b,a)\in R\implies (a,b)\in R^{-1}$
$(a,b)\in R^{-1} \implies (b,a)\in R\implies (a,b)\in R$

Therefore $R=R^{-1}$.

Comment: In the first part, you only use that R^{-1} \subseteq R. This isn't an issue, of course, just pointing out that the two-way implication holds if we only require the inverse of R to be contained in R.